# JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, tsx

I'm getting **JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF** in Expo app.
I'm not sure why this issue occurred.

```js
    export const serviceCaller = <TResp>(url: string, request: HttpRequest): Promise<TResp> => {
    return new Promise<TResp>(async (resolve) => {
            try {
            const response = await fetch(url, request);
            const json: TResp = await response.json();
                resolve(json);
            } catch (error) {
               console.log(error);
               resolve(null);
           }
        });
    };
```

**Error list**:

> - JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
> - node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
> - node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in
> - ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: sounds like you do not have valid JSON, add a debug line and figure out what you have

Comment: What is the Json that you are trying to parse?

Comment: I got that error when I received something different to JSON in `await response.json()`, for example, a internal server error at server side returns html instead JSON

Comment: I found issue. I'm getting null from API so that it was displaying JSON parse error.